# How can I make sure my value was add and exist and then run another code jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

You can see the code below, you can enter any value and then append it to the div. I want to add a code that make sure the value appear on the div first and make sure it is exist and then run the code. Because I am using .ajax to make a search function, so I want to make sure the value is exist in the div and the run the .ajax. So, I am thinking about if input_length is greater than current length, but I don't know if that correct or not. because input_length actually is the current length,right? Help, appreciate.

```js
$( "#input" ).keydown(function( event ) {

if ( event.which == 13 ) {
   event.preventDefault();
    
    //put input value into div
var value=$('#input').val();
    $('#word').append(" " + value);
        
}
  var input_length=$('#word').text.().length();
    //I want to code if one word add and exist, then run my .ajax code.
     
});
```

```css
.test {display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="word" id="word">dog</div>
<input type="text" id="input"/>
```

Comment: `var input_length=$('#word').length();` should be `var input_length=$('#word').text().length();`

Comment: Wait, so you want to make sure that people can't add the same word twice? Or what? I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: I want to make sure the value that I enter is exist in the div, so I can use .ajax to search.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but you can check to see if the word in question exists like this:

```
// With jQuery
var newWord = $('#input').val();
var wordContainer = $('#word');
if (wordContainer.text().indexOf(newWord) < 0) {
  wordContainer.append(' ' + newWord);
}

// Or with plain JavaScript
var newWord = document.getElementById('input').value;
var wordContainer = document.getElementById('word');
if (wordContainer.innerText.indexOf(word) < 0) {
  wordContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ' + word));
}
```

Both `append` and `appendChild` synchronously add the word, so you don't need to check after using them. It's *definitely* there. ;)

Comment: The reason I need to make sure the word exist, because I use the div value for my ajax value to search. For some reason, my ajax cannot catch the word in div sometime but not always, so I want to make sure the word exist, and call my ajax.

Comment: Both `append` and `appendChild` are synchronous methods. When your code reaches the line *after* those methods are called, the word *will* be in the DOM element.

There may be another logic error going on with your "ajax" (whatever that is referencing).